# Foundation 5. Jquery plugin is not working. Do I have to disable Foundation 5 Functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I am trying to implement a custom Jquery plugin into Foundation 5 but it does not seem to be reacting to the .hover command.

Here is the [plugin in codepen](http://codepen.io/new2code/pen/50b0fbdc2f422086532a04c5482d06f2/) and [here is the site](http://greenlightfinal.businesscatalyst.com/) I am trying to implement it on.

I was wondering if there is something I am missing? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On checking the code on your live site, i found the following generated HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">

<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="/_assets/js/arift.js"></script>

// Will retun 1 or 0 based on if user is logged in(1) or not logged in(0)
var _isLoggedIn = !!parseInt("0");
</script>
```

What i see is a script tag inside script tag. Just like Inception, you have ended up making Scripteption.

The ideal generated html should look like this

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/_assets/js/arift.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Will retun 1 or 0 based on if user is logged in(1) or not logged in(0)
var _isLoggedIn = !!parseInt("0");
</script>
```

Comment: You are welcome :) Can you mark this as correct answer if it has helped you? :)